# Use my_changes on core js file in cs-cart?

Tags: cs-cart

I want to make changes to the wysiwyg editor in CS-Cart, and I can do this by editing the file:

```
/js/tygh/editors/tinymce.editor.js
```

But this is a core file that should only be edited through the my_changes addon.

So the question is, how do I use my_changes to edit this file?

The my_changes addon is active and is used elsewhere successfully.

I have tried putting my edited js file in this folder:

```
/js/addons/my_changes/tygh/editors
```

But this does nothing.

In the file there appears to be a js hook:

```
$.ceEditor('handlers', editor);
```

How and where do I override the editor var?

Answer (score 1):

Use JS Hooks:

`$.ceEvent('trigger', 'ce.picker_add_js_item', [hook_data]);`

https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/core/coding_standards/hooks.html#js-hooks

If there is no hooks, then ask the CS-Cart developers to create it.

Comment: In `tinymce.editor.js` I have `$.ceEditor('handlers', editor);` is this a hook? Can you explain how I use it?

Comment: Or what file I should put my `$.ceEditor` override in?